# Conjunction and disjunction helper class

Tags: c#, extension-methods, helper, boolean

I had an idea to manifest, but i wanted to know if any one knows if it exits already.
Creating a Helper class that can get an action or a bool expression as many as it can get and return the bool output. maybe doing it like an extension method.

```
if(a==b.Or(a != c).And(IsBool).VerifyAll(numbers));
```

actually that can be a good idea, what do you say ?

**UPDATE**

My intention is get expressions of Boolean terms and join them to a single answer, for example

```
 public static bool Conjuntion(params bool[] expressions)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < expressions.Length; i++)
        {
            if (!expressions[i])
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Or

```
public static bool Disjuntion(params bool[] expressions)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < expressions.Length; i++)
        {
            if (!expressions[i])
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: What are `a`, `b` and `c` and what is their relationship to `numbers`? Did you mean lambda expressions instead?

Comment: How do the `Conjunction()` and `Disjuntion()` methods relate to your previous example? Why don't you just use `&&`s and `||`s? What is `VerifyAll()` supposed to do?

Answer (score 4):

Why reinvent the wheel?

```
if (numbers.All (a => (a == b || a != c) && IsBool (a)))
```

See [`Enumerable.All`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548541.aspx), [`Enumerable.Any`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972.aspx) for examples.

Comment: Sorry man, never intended to reinvent the wheel just make it rounder, Didn't know about the `Enumerable.All` and such, but my intention is to get any Boolean expression not in some kind of an array.

Comment: @guyl, “not in some kind of an array”, what array are you talking about?